Supabase query return null in flutter app
What's the correct way to retrieve supabase data in flutter?
I'm building up my code as below but seemed not to be parsing the response body the right way.
 sdk: ^3.1.1 supabase_flutter: ^2.0.0
In main.dart
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: supabase_db_url
    anonKey: supabase_db_key,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

In widget build
static Future<int> GET(Map<String, dynamic> params) async{
    final futureSpabaseOutput = Supabase.instance.client.from('table_name').select();
    return parseSupabaseOutput(futureSpabaseOutput);
  }


where
static int parseSupabaseOutput(responseBody) {
    int count = 10;
    if(count>=responseBody.length){
      return count = responseBody.length
    }
    return count;
  }

Got error
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'length'
method not found
Receiver: Instance of 'PostgrestFilterBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'

I suppose with a non-empty database with the below query response is list like but couldn't retrieve data anyways.

Perhaps you forgot to put await on your query? or .then((value){}). I haven't looked too deeply at your code but maybe that will be enough

You didn't wait to get the completed result:
final futureSpabaseOutput = Supabase.instance.client.from('table_name').select();

Fix
final futureSpabaseOutput = await Supabase.instance.client.from('table_name').select();

